# I can't print the column value or row value of Dataframes in julia. I am getting a not found error?

Tags: dataframe, julia, julia-dataframe

I searched a lot. I am reading the document. but still could not figure it out. Whichever way I try it says no column name and gives an error. Thank you in advance for your help

```
print(daf[!,:SPV])
```

Output:

```
  ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: column name :SPV not found in the data frame
```

My Dataset:

```
            12×2 DataFrame
            Row │ valuecols           values
                │ Symbol              Any
            ─────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────
            1 │ PointId             Any[5054, 5054, 5054, 5054, 5054…
            2 │ ŞUBE İSİM           Any["EVKUR - ADIYAMAN MERKEZ", "…
            3 │ SPV                 Any["M. SERKAN EKINCI", "M. SERK…
            4 │ Merch               Any["SEMIH AYDOGAN", "SEMIH AYDO…
            5 │ PAZAR PAYI          Any[43.3333, 41.688, 37.0787, 30…
            6 │ Il                  Any["ADIYAMAN", "MALATYA", "MALA…
            7 │ ılce                Any["MERKEZ", "MERKEZ", "MERKEZ"…
            8 │ Adres               Any["HOCA OMER MH. ATATURK CAD. …
            9 │ X Satış Adeti       Any["-", "-", 300, 15, 23, 4, 6,…
            10 │ Toplam Satış Adeti  Any["-", "-", 750, 15, 23, 6, 6,…
            11 │ Xg Ciro             Any["-", "-", 600000.0, 50000.0,…
            12 │ Toplam Ciro         Any["-", "-", 1.3e6, 160000.0, 2…
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that is indeed your DataFrame `daf` then as you can see there is no column named `SPV`. There are two columns in your output (`valuecols` and `values`) and 12 rows containing what you seem to have intended to be columns. Without seeing the code that created `daf` I can't tell you exactly what went wrong but you can transform it into the structure that you want by doing:

```
DataFrame(map(Pair, daf.valuecols, daf.values))
```